# How to get written permission or letter for google's impersonation policy

Tags: google-play, google-play-console, google-developers-console

In Feb I upload an app on play store but now I get some violation email and my app was removed from google play store. I thought it's a normal issue and i will fix it. After 1 day I got another mail from google play and my app was suspended. the reason was impersonation policy. They explain that the logo and title is copied but this is wrong I created logo and title myself. So the question is how to deal with it, my app has over 1m download.

1. Should I registered trademark ?
2. My appeal was rejected.
3. They ask me to show letter or some written permission. But from where I get this permission because there is no firm and company registered same as my app's name or logo.

If someone wants to help please suggest what could I do

Comment: Sorry. StackOverflow is for programming questions only.

Comment: give us more info

Comment: Tell us when you find the anwser, same issue here.